# math.gcd() vs Euclidean Algo

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is the most efficient way to find the gcd of two numbers, using math.gcd() function after importing `math` library or

```
def computegcd(x,y):
    while(y):
        x,y = y,x%y
    return x
```

Comment: If `while(y): x,y = y,x%y return x` were the most efficient way to find the GCD, why would `math.gcd()` not be implemented as that?

Answer (score 3):

you can use [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) to check it yourself :)

run this:

```py
from timeit import timeit
import math
import random

x = random.randint(9 ** 6, 9 ** 7)
y = random.randint(5 ** 5, 5 ** 6)


def with_math():
    return math.gcd(x, y)


def with_euclid():
    xx = x
    yy = y
    while yy:
        xx, yy = yy, xx % yy
    return xx


print(with_math() == with_euclid())  # Make sure result is same
print(timeit(with_math, number=10**7))
print(timeit(with_euclid, number=10**7))
```

on my current laptop it outputs:

```
True
3.021651975000168
7.143860205000237
```

Comment: note: time results could vary, but most runs I got a ratio of about 2x in favor of `math.gcd()`

Comment: Do you where can i get the exact code or algorithm behind the math.gcd() function ?

Comment: @crazysa at the CPython's repo `mathmodule.c`: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/mathmodule.c#L839

Comment: actually the real real code is here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/196a530e00d88a138973bf9182e013937e293f97/Objects/longobject.c#L4875